# How to reset password in passport-local strategy in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

Passport.js provides authentication framework in Node.js. It only deals with Authentication.

Now I would like to enable password reset. Since there is no password field in User model, only passports, how can I reset password in passport-local strategy? I assume that user needs to generate a new password and call something to override the existing hash of the old password. What methods are those and where can I find them?

Comment: How are you storing the password without the password field?

Comment: passport-local strategy supposedly auto generated a password for each user and stored it somewhere. I do not know where it is stored and how to change it.

Comment: Can you add the code for your User model ?. AFAIK passport-local strategy requires a username and password field. Please refer this - http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects to reset his/her password, what you can do is send an email to the user with a link containing a token associated with the user. Once the user clicks on the link, you validate the user based on the token & email and then show the reset password HTML. Once user enters the new password, in the backend code, you set the password on the `User` object after hashing and then save it. You can set the token as null too.

A sample code with base64 will be as shown below

```
user.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
user.password = user.hashPassword('newPassword');   
user.token = undefined;
user.save(...)
```

The hashPassword method is as given.

```
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
    if (this.salt && password) {
        return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
    } else {
        return password;
    }
};
```

The above code is auto-generated with Yeoman